# Magento 2: How to separate this plugin into 2 different fields

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have import this plugin in my project **https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input**. Now I split into 1 field dial_code, 1 field phone but when i choose dial_code and click outside. The value cannot save in this input and disappear.

Can any one help me with this?

Billions of Thanks in Advance